# How to properly use matplotlib render an image histogram?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a python small program to obtain the grayscale histogram for an image. I'm using OpenCV and matplotlib but I'm not getting good results when trying to display the graph.

This is what I'm doing:

1. Convert to grayscale.
2. Create a 256 length list of zeros.
3. Iterate over each pixel, get its grayscale value and increment in 1 the value of list at same position in list of the pixel grayscale value.
4. Later, try to use matplotlib `hist` function. But I'm not getting expected result.

This is what I'm trying:

```
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], 0)
# cv2.imshow("Imagen",img)
height, width = img.shape
print height
print width
hist = [0] * 256
print hist
for y in xrange(height):
    for x in xrange(width):
        pixel = img[y,x]
        hist[pixel] = hist[pixel] + 1
print hist
print max(hist)
pyplot.hist(hist,256, range=(0,255))
pyplot.show()
```

I just printed the min and max value and max is 4001, and this is what I'm obtaining.

[image]

How can I obtain a proper plot?

Note: I know there are this and other implementations with OpenCV but in this case I have to code it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do `pyplot.hist(hist,256, range=(0,255))`, since this is trying to aggregate the data for you, but you've already aggregated it yourself.

Try this

```
pyplot.plot(hist)
```

Comment: `plt.bar(hist)`, no ?

Comment: I think an image histogram is traditionally presented as a line chart rather than a bar chart, the histogram refers to the the aggregation step.